# Android app that shows start date of yearly recurring calendar events

Tags: android, calendar

I'm looking for an app for Android that show the start date of yearly recurring events.

Using the Samsung Calendar and Calendar+ I can edit the whole event recursion, but they always show the current instance year and not the start date (i.e. when the recursion begins).

I used the yearly recurring events to store the birthdays of contacts that I don't have in my contacts list and the start date is the day of birth (with the correct year) so I can get the age by looking for the number of recursions. Unfortunately, it's not easy to edit them after creation, hence this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an Android app that has this feature: **Calengoo** (paid).

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.calengoo.android

[image: Screenshot with the setting "display age of annual events"]